# Virtuemart combine attributes to adjust the price

Tags: php, joomla, attributes, virtuemart

Is it possible to combine different attributes to calculate the price.
Like, if I have to attributes, and when I have a attribute with 5 and a attribute with 4, that I can somehow create a combination, so (for example) that the price becomes (5 x 4 = ) 20.

Comment: You will have to modify the core for something like this.

Comment: I don't think you can do mulitplicative, but IIRC you can set each attribute's value to add a relative value to the price. Colour: red +$5, Blue +$10; Size Small +$10, Medium +$20, Large +$30. Such that a red in Medium is baseprice + $25.